# Nagios check_tcp ESTABLISHED connections

Tags: nagios

I am interested in seeing if clients are connected to us on lets say port 63004. Now check_tcp works well to see if port is available. Unfortunatley I need to know if the port is in a LISTENING state or ESTABLISHED. is it possible to check if the state of the port is ESTABLISHED as we are in a listening state and await clients connecting to us

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to write your own check script.

Something like this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

connections=`netstat -pant | grep :63004 |grep ESTABLISHED |wc -l`

if [ $connections -gt 0 ]; then
  echo -n "There are $connections established"
  exit 0
else
  echo -n "There are no established connections"
  exit 1
fi
```

You should, of course, elaborate on the script, and make it something more robust than something slapped together in a couple minutes to answer a Serverfault question.

Comment: Thanks cjc. I figured scripting it would cover my needs.